# Creating a custom language syntax checker / highlight error in VSCODE

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, plsql

I have a file with some custom syntax, I'd like vscode to highlight keywords and check that the syntax is correct.

sample file:

```
{
    someLogic: [
        {
            action: "someAction",
            debug: true,
            myQuery: "
        
            declare
                a       number := 5;
                b       number := 7;
                sum     number;

            begin 
                sum := a + b;
                dbms_output.put_line('a + b: ' || sum);
            end;",

            params: ["val", "val2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see the file consists of key value pairs where the key is not surrounded by "" and
the value may be a plsql code block string.
and there could be arrays, objects.
It's basically a "relaxed" json parser where the keys is not surrounded by "" and value might not be surrounded either (special case for debug: true)
I'd like vscode to highlight syntax / provide autocomplete in the file.

What are the steps to doing so?
I'd like this new 'language' to be available globally in vscode.

Thank you.

Comment: Check language extensions: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview

Comment: create a TextMate Grammar and add this to an extension